# Hibernate: Iterating batch of objects and updating the same

Tags: hibernate, pagination, insert-update

I want to iterate over a list of entities in batches and want to update a specific field in the same entity. The logic I am trying to use is as below:

```
private void process()
{
    int index = 0;
    boolean hasMore = true

    while (hasMore)
    {
            List<Model> models = DAO.getModels(index, batchSize); // batchSize is configurable
             if (models != null && models.size() == 0)
             {
                    System.out.println("found zero   ");
                    hasMore = false;
                    break;
             }

             processModels(models);
             index = index + batchSize;
    }
}
```

The get models method has an HQL query like the following:

```
String hqlQuery = "from Model ac where ac.syncflag ='N'"
```

The processModels() method processes these Model objects and based on some logic sets the syncflag value to 'Y'.

The processModel() method looks like this:

```
private void processModel()
{
if (models != null && models.size() > 0)
        {
            for (Model model : models)
            {
                this.updateFlagForModel(model);

            }
            }
        }

}

private void updateFlagForModel(Model model)
{
  // some processing........
    model.setFlag(true);
    DAO.saveOrUpdate(model);
}
```

However, as I am iterating and updating the same objects the batching logic is getting disturbed and I am not able to process the correct number of records.

Can someone please help? Do i need to add some extra logic in the query part to handle this?

Regards

Comment: 'not able to process the correct number of records' - how are we supposed to know what you mean by that? Please provide a detailed and precise problem description.

Comment: BTW is there a reason you are not using bulk updates?

Comment: The iteration logic breaks and could not process correctly. Let's say I have a total of 9 records which I want to process. When I do not do an actual update and verify the logic by putting some logger statements, I could see all 9 records available for processing. However, the same logic with actual update operation is breaking and all the records are not getting processed. Even the System.out statement (System.out.println("found zero   ");) is not getting printed.

Comment: Please let me reiterate to see if I got this right - directly after the `DAO.getModels`, you do have the records you expect. inside the `processModel` method, the collection is somehow broken. If this is correct, please add the `processModel` source to your question - the code you have posted does not manipulate the List.

Comment: Edited the question with some more details

Comment: The code looks reasonable. There is no line that does modify the List, so I have no idea. I would advise debugging through the method. And, if feasible, you can often save some headaches by using bulk updates for simple entity updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imagine you have the interval from min(id):1 to max(id):10000 with syncflag ='N'. Lets decide 50 as each select size. so first page will be like below

`select ac from Model ac where ac.syncflag ='N' and id>=1 and id < 51` (you keep processing those records)
next time do the query as below

```
select ac from Model ac where ac.syncflag ='N' and id>=51 and id < 101
```

and then it will go till

```
select ac from Model ac where ac.syncflag ='N' and id>=9951 and id < 10001
```

if there are more records at the end you can again make new set of batch iteration till it ends.